Change Link popup (to open link in a new tab)
I would like to adjust popup (Ctrl K)
Here is a default version

I would like to add a checkbox that control if link should open in a new tab:

How do I do it? Can anybody give me a hint or direction?
I have checked similar posts but most of them were about CKEditor3 or CKEditor4 and I have CKEditor5.
Thanks.
